# inserting all permutations of letters into sqlite

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-insert

I want insert all possible 3 digits permutations in my list of characters with their Hash Values into Sqllite.Can any body help me fixing this piece of code: Besides, i am using sqliteexpert with a Cryptable with 2 fields : 1) PlainText and 2) Md5Hash, it same as sqlite3 to import as the code?

I tried:

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.md5()
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('pr.db')
c = conn.cursor()
#print hashlib.md5("a").hexdigest()
mylist =[1,"A",3,"B",5,6,7,8,9,10]
print len(mylist)

for i in range(len(mylist)):
print hashlib.md5(str(mylist[i])).hexdigest()
c.execute('insert into Cryptable values (i)' , hashlib.md5(i))
connection.commit()
for j in range(len(mylist)):
c.execute('insert into Cryptable values (j)' , hashlib.md5(j))
connection.commit()
for k in range(len(mylist)):
c.execute('insert into Cryptable values (k)' , hashlib.md5(k))
connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [permutations](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.permutations) from [itertools](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#module-itertools) and call [`hexdigest`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest) to get the hash as a string:

```
from hashlib import md5
from itertools import permutations

alphabet = "AB13567890"
perm_length = 3
perms = map("".join, permutations(alphabet, perm_length))
hashes = [md5(k).hexdigest() for k in perms]

for hash in hashes:
    # print("Do sql stuff: {}".format(hash))
```

Comment: Dear Butch , can you please help me to edit my own code , not using itertools?